# Google and Huawei APK flavor build issue

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, android-build-flavors, appgallery, huawei-iap

I setup my project for flavors build (Google & Huawei) according to this doc - https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor.

Here are my build scripts. I have tried including the signature in the release build with no change.

app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.testapp"
    }

    flavorDimensions "platform"
    productFlavors {
        huawei {
            versionCode 1712
            versionName "1.7.12"
            targetSdkVersion 29
            minSdkVersion 26
            buildTypes {
                resValue("string", "ad_app_id", "103959507")
                release {
                    resValue("string", "ad_id", "g87ta7hatb")
                    minifyEnabled true
                    proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
                    debuggable = true
                }
                debug {
                    resValue("string", "ad_id", "testf9tx29xur5")
                    debuggable = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0'

    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-lite:13.4.32.300'
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-apms:1.3.1.300'
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.4.1.300'
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-crash:1.4.1.300'
    huaweiImplementation 'com.huawei.hms:iap:5.0.1.300'
}

apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```

project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.3.0.300'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'
        }
    }
}
```

The environment is failing with `60054: url is null`.
The gradle build is also picking up the file location:
`--W- The variant: huaweiRelease, Use the json file: /Users/xxx/Documents/myappGoogle/app/src/release/agconnect-services.json`

I have tried the flavor tags and have tried placing the json file within the flavor directory as the post stated here - https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201313999391430187&fid=0101187876626530001. The file so far has been picked up when placed in the app directory, the src/debug(release) directories, and also in the src/flavor directories. I can clearly see in the build logs that the correct file is being found by the build script.

What's also odd to me is the documentation:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/iap-ExceptionHandlingAndGeneralErrorCodes-v4
says that `60054 is iap is not supported in this country`, but the actual code is returning `60054: url is null`.

The error code being returned, `iapApiException.getStatus()`
is returning `status.statusCode = 60054`
and `status.getStatusMessage = "url is null"`.
This is from `isEnvReady` which is in contradiction to the aforementioned documentation in which status code 60054 should be `OrderStatusCode.ORDER_ACCOUNT_AREA_NOT_SUPPORTED`
where as if this was actually a url error I would expect error 60001
`OrderStatusCode.ORDER_STATE_PARAM_ERROR`
or something along those lines.

I am thinking of the possibility with merge issue due to this document:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/Environment_installation
The reason for my suspicion is that my AndroidManifest is clearly missing the appid that is supposed to be included through the scripts.

Am I missing something here? What is your suggestion or what else should I look into? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try putting `apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'` just below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.

Answer (score 0):

1．Please check whether you have copy the **agconnect-services.json** file to the folder of each build type.
2．Please check whether you have modify configuration files to adapt to multiple flavors.

For details, see the [documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor).

The result code of 60054 may be returned when HUAWEI IAP is supported by a country or region but there is a service error. In this case:

1. Please provide your appid to check the info.
2. Please provide full log: `adb logcat >xxx.log` to obtain it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issue with the flavor build but it is the issue with using USA HUAWEI ID in testing. The right solution is a developer should create another non-USA  HUAWEI ID and then log into the phone.  After opening App Gallery App, change the Settings of country to a country that supports IAP(for example like UK). Remove USA SIM card and then use the IAP service after connecting to the changed country in the Setting using VPN.